# Is it possible to run the Kitty GUI on Ubuntu or Debian?

Tags: ssh, windows, putty

As it is possible to run [Putty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) on Linux, I assume it will likely be easy to run its variant [Kitty](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/), on Ubuntu/Debian.

I don't have an Ubuntu/Debian machine with [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) (I have only a Ubuntu server machine) and as I love Kitty I want to know if it is possible to run it in Ubuntu or Debian "as is", without modifying any of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your own link:

> **What is KiTTY ?**
>
> KiTTY is a fork from version 0.70 of PuTTY, the best telnet / SSH
> client in the world. **KiTTY is only designed for the Microsoft®
> Windows® platform**. For more information about the original software,
> or pre-compiled binaries on other systems, you can go to the [Simon Tatham PuTTY page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/).

So for the alterations made to Kitty to work with Linux you need to ...

- Find out what those changes are.
- Add them to the source code for Putty, the Linux version.
- Compile it, and probably rebrand it.

Comment: I didn't read the content of the link at all - it just seemed to me good, from the page title and description and google and location in google SERP as something for newcomers.